# JS FQL to Comment_Info keeps returning: "Service temporarily unavailable"

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-comments

I run a very basic FQL query with JavaScript, and keep getting back an error Object `{error_code: "2", error_msg: "Service temporarily unavailable", request_args: Array[8]}`

My aim is to read the `comment_info.XID` of the recent comments posted via Facebook to my website (all the website, not limited to a specific post).

This is my code, based on some samples posted on StackOverflow mostly:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div id="fbcomments"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    var fb_app_id = '*';

    FB.init({
        appId    : fb_app_id,
        session : null, // don't refetch the session when PHP already has it
        status  : true, // check login status
        cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml    : true // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {

        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            if (response.authResponse) {

                var fb_access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken; // I even tried hard-coding the value from: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred

                FB.api(
                    {
                        method: 'fql.query',
                        query: 'SELECT xid,count FROM comments_info WHERE app_id="'+fb_app_id+'"',
                        access_token : fb_access_token
                    },
                    function(newresponse) {
                        $.each(newresponse, function(i, e) {
                             $("#fbcomments").append(""+e.text+""); // we get here, but e.text is undefined (see my error on top)
                        });         

                    }
                ); //FB.api
                    } else { //response.authResponse
                        console.log('no response.authResponse');// do something...maybe show a login prompt
                    }
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                console.log(' not_authorized')
            } else {
                console.log('not_logged_in')
            }
    });
};

</script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> (function(d){ var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;} js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/he_IL/all.js#appId=*&amp;xfbml=1";d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js); }(document)); </script>
```

Notes:

1. I AM the admin of the app for which the `app_id` is used.
2. Once I succeed in this current task, I plan on wrapping this FQL query with a match to table `comments` that will return the actual comment body, not just its `XID`.
3. Using standard `graph.facebook` will only return comments for specific page url. I want all the comments made to my website.
4. I don't want to iFrame the [Facebook Comments Moderation Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?id=).

I tried:

1. using and not using `FB.init({'session'...}`
2. [hard coding](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=) `fb_access_token`.
3. using and not using `#app_id=*` in the `<script src="">` value.
4. logging out of Facebook, logging in, and etc.
5. waiting a few days (even two weeks) between running this query.

**UPDATE:**

I used PHP as well, but got the same error. This is my PHP script:

```
// get user access_token
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=$app_id&client_secret=$app_secret&grant_type=client_credentials";

// response is of the format "access_token=AAAC..."
$access_token = substr(file_get_contents($token_url), 13);

$config = array(
        'appId'  => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user_id) {
    $params = array(
            'method' => 'fql.query',
            'query' => "SELECT xid,count FROM comments_info WHERE app_id=$app_id",
            'access_token' => $access_token
    );

    try {
        $result = $facebook->api($params);
        var_dump($result);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }


} else {
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
}
```

Nothing seems to work.
Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Reading from that table requires an _app_ access token, and that should not be exposed in public client-side code.

Comment: If I get the app access token via PHP, will the javascript identify it automatically?

Comment: If you are using PHP anyway, then do your query in PHP in the first place - again, your app access token should _never_ be exposed client-side.

Comment: PHP did not work either. I got the same error :(
You may see my PHP code updated in the original question above...

Comment: any other suggestions?